# Model binding of nested properties in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm wanting to get some binding working in my mvc application. I find nested properties are not automatically bound by the default model binder in the RC1 release of asp.net mvc. I have the following class structure:

```
public class Contact{  
    public int Id { get; set; }  
    public Name Name { get; set; }  
    public string Email { get; set; }  
}
```

Where `Name` is defined as:

```
public class Name{  
    public string Forename { get; set; }  
    public string Surname { get; set; }  
}
```

My view is defined along the lines of:

```
using(Html.BeginForm()){  
    Html.Textbox("Name.Forename", Model.Name.Forename);  
    Html.Textbox("Name.Surname", Model.Name.Surname);  
    Html.Textbox("Email", Model.Email);  
    Html.SubmitButton("save", "Save");  
}
```

My controller action is defined as:

```
public ActionResult Save(int id, FormCollection submittedValues){  
    Contact contact = get contact from database;  
    UpdateModel(contact, submittedValues.ToValueProvider());  

    //at this point the Name property has not been successfully populated using the default model binder!!!
}
```

The `Email` property is successfully bound but not the `Name.Forename` or `Name.Surname` properties. Can anyone tell if this should work using the default model binder and I'm doing something wrong or if it doesn't work and I need to roll my own code for binding nested properties on model objects?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the problem is due to the Name prefix on the properties.  I think you'll need to update it as two models and specify the prefix for the second one.  Note that I've removed the `FormCollection` from the parameters and used the signature of `UpdateModel` that relies on the built-in value provider and specifies a whitelist of properties to consider.

```
 public ActionResult Save( int id )
 {
     Contact contact = db.Contacts.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

     UpdateModel(contact, new string[] { "Email" } );
     string[] whitelist = new string[] { "Forename", "Surname" };
     UpdateModel( contact.Name, "Name", whitelist );
 }
```

Comment: SingleOrDefault can directly be called with a lamda expression

Answer (score 5):

To bind a Name rather than the whole view model on POST is to instruct the model binder that a prefix will be used. This is done using the BindAttribute.

```
public ActionResult AddComment([Bind(Prefix = "Name")] Name name)
{
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Thats very interesting because if you had done

```
public ActionResult Save( int id, Contact contact )
{
    //contact here would contain the nested values.
}
```

I'm using this with great success. 
I suppose then you could somehow sync the two Contact objects together.

I would have thought that the UpdateModel and the binding to the parameter use the same call behind the scenes. note: haven't tried to reproduce your issue.